# How can CFWindows be printed

Tags: css, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfwindow

We have begun using CFWindows extensively on our website, ever since our upgrade to ColdFusion 9.  Today one of our users pointed out that they cannot print a page with an active CFWindow.  The CFWindow prints out transparent with the background page showing through.

We had a color issue a while ago and styled the back of the CFWindow to a solid color:

```
<style>
    .x-window-mc { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
</style>
```

We tried both with and without this style, but with no success.  Our target browser is IE8 at this time.

How can we make our CFWindows opaque so that they will appear correctly when the user initiates a browser print command?

Comment: Stop using cfwindow. It is the path to the Dark Side. Don't cripple yourself by using the UI stuff in ColdFusion. Using jQueryUI, or any other JS library, is easier, and in the long run, will be better supported and make you a better developer.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but that is no longer an option.  Too much work would be required to make such a change right now.

Comment: Change it now..or change it later...eventually, you will likely find a need to change it. :D

Comment: @ScottStroz : Wasn't cfwindow powered by a not ancient version of extjs?

Comment: I cannot recall the version of extJs that is used in CF9, but I can guarantee it is not the latest version...nor will it ever be updated. You are stuck on what ever version Adobe included - which means if there were any big bugs....you are screwed if using cfwindow. If you want to use extJS, then use it....don't use ColdFusion's half-baked implementation of it. Contrary to what others say, it is NOT easier to use with ColdFusion.

Comment: *the version of extJs that is used in CF9* Both CF9/10 are bundled with v3.1

Comment: And current version of extJS is 4.2. So CF 9 & 10 are a full version behind, with no way to upgrade. Stop using cfwindow and other UI components in ColdFusion, you will paint yourself into a corner.